# How to make a new type based on generic, which includes object and interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I want to create a new data type based on an object and its interface. In an interface, keys can be optional( | undefined), but if they are in the object, they should become required.

Example:

```
export type MakeRequiredType<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {
    [P in K]-?: T[P];
};
interface personInterface {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    title?: string;
}

const person: personInterface = {
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
};

type OptionalToRequiredData = MakeRequiredType<personInterface, keyof typeof person>;//Get new type

const resultPerson: OptionalToRequiredData = {
    id: 2,//This field becomes mandatory
    name: 'John',//This field becomes mandatory
    title: ''//Still not a required field, since person doesn't have one
};
```

I tried writing a type, but the problem is that it takes keys not from an object, but from the type of that object (keyof typeof person) and makes all keys in the output required.
I know that fields can be accessed using person.name! or person.name?, I need to change the data type specifically

Comment: Use `satisfies` instead of a type annotation: `const person = { ... } satisfies personInterface`

Comment: This will work if the type/interface is not strictly defined on the object, which is exactly my situation.